# Ecto: Where - Or

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

It looks like [a simple feature](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/640e8f5f7f97eab68e4eebcd517803f71d90ebc1) is coming for this issue, but [Phoenix Ecto](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto) doesn't have it yet. What is a workaround in the meantime for a where-or query in Ecto?

For example:

```
from(u in User,
    left_join: up in assoc(u, :user_projects),
    # does not work
    where: up.project_id != ^project.id OR up.project_id IS NULL,
    select: {u.id, u.username})
```

Comment: `where: up.project_id != ^project.id or is_nil(up.project_id)`?

Comment: @Dogbert I did try that, but it throws an error: "`is_nil?(up.project_id())` is not a valid query expression."

Comment: Did you write `is_nil?` or `is_nil`? It should be `is_nil`.

Comment: @dogbert why so I did. This is giving me the expected results, thank you! If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you've misunderstood what `or_where` will do -- what you want can be done with a simple `or` and `is_nil`:

```
where: up.project_id != ^project.id or is_nil(up.project_id)
```

What `or_where` does is enable you to join multiple `where: expr` in an Ecto query with an `OR` instead of `AND`. In the current version of Ecto (2.0), there is no straightforward way to do that -- Ecto joins all `where` expressions with an `AND`.

Answer (score -2):

Just replace `OR` by `and` with `not`

```
from(u in User,
left_join: up in assoc(u, :user_projects),
where: up.project_id != ^project.id AND not(is_nil(up.project_id)),
select: {u.id, u.username})
```

This is more ecto way, by the way

Comment: The `AND` clause in your example is redundant with the first (`!=`) clause and does not give me the desired union of the two possibilities.